# Running sum and percentage calculated on a specific row in pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, cumulative-sum

I wrote this stored procedure that returns the data perfectly as expected in an Excel-like table. Now I would like to add 2 columns:

1. Sum of the values of all previous columns
2. Calculate the percentage of this sum calculated on the sum of the last row

I tried to calculate directly in the first select but no way.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_presenze
(
    @month VARCHAR(6),
    @group INT
) 
AS 
BEGIN

 SELECT FINCode,  Nachname, Vorname, Gruppe, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]   
FROM  (SELECT        BK_Athleten.FINCode, BK_Athleten.Nachname, BK_Athleten.Vorname, BK_Athleten.Gruppe, RIGHT(BK_Einheiten.Datum, 2) AS Day, BK_Anwesend.IDPres
FROM            BK_Anwesend INNER JOIN
                         BK_Athleten ON BK_Anwesend.FINCode = BK_Athleten.FINCode INNER JOIN
                         BK_Einheiten ON BK_Anwesend.IDEinheit = BK_Einheiten.IDEinheit
                         WHERE BK_Athleten.Gruppe = @group AND LEFT(BK_Einheiten.Datum, 6) = @month) AS PVT

PIVOT  
(  
Count(IDPres) 
FOR Day IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], 
[16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31] )  
) AS PRT

END
```

Comment: can you define `sum the values of all previous columns?`. Like column 2 is the sum of 2 and 1... 3 is the sum of 3, 2, and 1?

Comment: No. The values in the previous columns are a count of the occurences in the original SQL table (the training sessions per athlete per day)

Comment: What I would do is calculate this data in a separate subquery, based on the original data, to get a result something like ID, TotalSum, Percent. Then in your main query, join to that subquery to get the data to display.